# Почему не работает JavaScript в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не работает вроде бы простой скрипт с сайтом, путь указан верно.

HTML - строка подключения

```
<script  src="script.js"></script>
```

HTML - описание элемента

```
<div class="paragraph_team" >
    <div class="button">
        <button id="btn" onclick="readAll()">+</button>
    </div>

    <div class="paragraph_text" id="dn">
        <div class="pt">
            <h4>Badass Features</h4>

            <p id="top">Lorem </p>
            <p id="buttom"><br>Morbi malesuada mi sem. Duis tristique elementum tristique. Sed ac magna quis erat sagittis suscipit. Phasellus faucibus rhoncus massa, non laoreet lorem fringilla non.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#dn {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
function readAll() {
    var dn = document.getElementByID("dn");
    if(dn.style.display === "none") {
        dn.style.display = "inline";
        btn.innerHTML = "-";
    }
    else {
        dn.style.display = "block";
        btn.innerHTML = "+";
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementById`, опечатка

Comment: Обычно, когда js не работает, то в консоли браузера есть ошибка, желательно ее прикладывать к сообщению.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ещё убрать нежелательный пробел в самом последнем < /div>

2) Четвёртую снизу строку JS переписать так: dn.style.display = "none";

3) Если строка подключения JS в самом начале всего кода, то переместить её в конец.

```
И всё зарааботтает.
```